# I'm trying to create a model matrix for a dataframe with dim 99k * 41. However, model.matrix requires a lot of memory. Why so?

Tags: r, r-caret

I have a dataframe with 99k rows and 35 columns. When I add 6 new dummy columns, the memory requirement to create a model.matrix jumps to 13.7Gb. I don't understand why!

I am on a windows 10 x64 machine with 8 GB ram running R 3.5.3. I have tried it on different machines but the problem remains.

Comment: can you post a sample of your data using `dput()`?

Comment: you may also want to look at `sparseMatrix()` in the Matrix package.

Comment: Thanks @Wil sparseMatrix() worked fine for me.